# AD FS OAuth2: NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to follow the tutorial found here: https://vcsjones.com/2015/05/04/authenticating-asp-net-5-to-ad-fs-oauth/ to configure OAuth authentication with an AD FS server.

This is my raw exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleSignInAsync(SignInContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.<SignInAsync>d__61.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<SignInAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRemoteCallbackAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

This is my ConfigureServices() method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(opts => opts.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.Configure<OAuthOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            opt.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            opt.AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.ClientId = "44ADBF90-0626-4730-8EC7-2D007F59B8D3";
            opt.ClientSecret = "abc123!";
            opt.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth-callback");
            opt.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = ctx =>
                {
                    var parameter = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        ["resource"] = "https://myapp.dev"
                    };
                    var query = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(ctx.RedirectUri, parameter);
                    ctx.Response.Redirect(query);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                {
                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(ctx.AccessToken);
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims, ctx.Options.AuthenticationScheme, "upn", "role");
                    ctx.Ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), ctx.Ticket.Properties, ctx.Options.AuthenticationScheme);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
            opt.ClaimsIssuer = "https://myapp.dev";
            opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize/";
            opt.TokenEndpoint = "https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/oauth2/token/";
        });

        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(opt =>
        {
            opt.AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            opt.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        });
    }
```

And my Configure() method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseCookieAuthentication();
        app.UseOAuthAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

**EDIT**
Project dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"StyleCop.Analyzers": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "build"
},
"System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0",
```

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory, the "Specified method is not supported". What versions of the packages are you using?

Comment: @DavidG dependencies added to question

Answer (score 2):

Your OAuth2 middleware registration uses an authentication scheme that is already taken by the cookies middleware:

```
opt.AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Change it to a unique value (e.g `ADFS`) and it should work.